# Orchard CMS module that uses HTTP session state

Tags: session-state, orchardcms

I'm trying to write a simple shopping cart Orchard module that will store items in session state and then read them out when the user wants to check out. It needs to work for anonymous users.

I've downloaded the Jumpstart module but have not been able to find any way to get access to the session in the handler or the driver.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply inject IHttpContextAccessor into the constructor of your driver or handler. Then you can call accessor.Current() and get access to the Session

Comment: Thanks. I've got access to the session in the driver.